# delete place from dynamic array of pointers- bytes lost - c

Tags: c

I keep getting lost bytes each time I delete place in the array.
In the first time I did: `///*mens[index] = mens[index + 1];*/`
but it made more lost bytes.would like to get your help!!

```
user_** deleteMen(user_** mens,int* numMens, int index)
{

    int f;
    if (index >=(*numMens))
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        return mens;
    }
    //free the index string
    free(mens[index]->userName);
    free(mens[index]->description);
    free(mens[index]->password);
    free(mens[index]->name);
    free(mens[index]->lastName);
    free(mens[index]->userId);
    for (f = index; f < *numMens - 1; f++)
    {
        mens[f]->age = mens[f + 1]->age;
        mens[f]->description = mens[f + 1]->description;
        mens[f]->gender = mens[f + 1]->gender;
        mens[f]->hobbies = mens[f+ 1]->hobbies;
        mens[f]->lastName = mens[f + 1]->lastName;
        mens[f]->name = mens[f + 1]->name;
        mens[f]->password = mens[f + 1]->password;
        mens[f]->userId = mens[f + 1]->userId;
        mens[f]->userName = mens[f + 1]->userName;
    }
    free(mens[*numMens - 1]->description);
    free(mens[*numMens - 1]->lastName);
    free(mens[*numMens - 1]->name);
    free(mens[*numMens - 1]->password);
    free(mens[*numMens - 1]->userId);
    free(mens[*numMens - 1]->userName);
    free(mens[*numMens - 1]);
    mens= (user_**)realloc(mens, (*numMens-1) * sizeof(user_*));
    if (mens == NULL)
        if (*numMens != 1)
            exit(1);
    *numMens-=1;
    return mens;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is currently *unclear*. We cannot help without knowing how `mens` and its elements have been allocated... Anyway, you should pay attention to formatting (I did it for your), and really, really you should read [ask] and follow its advices...

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Use also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Provide some [MCVE] in your question (so an entire program with a `main`, but reduced as much as possible). StackOverflow is not a *debug-my-code* service, so you need to ask explicitly a precise question

Comment: Why free the memory if you are just going to manually write the same locations again?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal: it could make sense if the members are pointers to allocated memory - what we cannot currently be sure...

Answer (score 0):

To begin with: you use *signed* int for indices and num. Input could be negative then(!), so you would have to check for. You avoid this problem if you use *unsigned* types (especially, as negative indices and array lengths are meaningless anyway). I personally would use `size_t` for.

Shortened your code a bit:

```
free(mens[index]->userName);
// ...
for (f = index; f < *numMens - 1; f++)
{
    mens[f]->age = mens[f + 1]->age;
    // ...
}

// these are wrong: you moved them to preceeding list element already
// (unless it was the last element itself, but then you freed them directly
// before entering the loop)
free(mens[*numMens - 1]->description);

// but I assume you instead want to delete the last element instead:

free(mens[*numMens - 1]);
```

You can have this part easier, though:

```
free(mens[index]->userName);
// ...

free(mens[index]);

for (f = index; f < *numMens - 1; f++)
{
    mens[f] = mens[f + 1];
}
```

The re-alloc part is questionable, though:

1. result of passing zero size is [*implementation defined*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) – you might or not get a null pointer, memory might or not be freed.
2. Since C11, support for zero size is deprecated.

Reducing memory in size might force the user of the function into a new `realloc` as soon as she or he adds another element to the array, which might not be to her/his favour...

My personal recommendation:

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    user_** data; // maybe even better: user_* data??? - depends on use case, though
} List;
```

This struct holds all relevant data together at one place, if you use it for your insertion/deletion functions, you are better off. You'd increase memory, if running out of capacity, but leave reduction to the user (maybe have a separate function for convenience, though).

If you feel reminded to C++: Yes, the basic idea is stolen from there (`std::vector`)...